# Open Flask static file on Bluemix

Tags: python, flask, ibm-cloud

I'm trying to open an image in my Flask app's static folder with PIL. When I run locally, it works. When I deploy to Bluemix, it doesn't find the image.

```
from PIL import Image
jpg = Image.open('static/images/image.jpg')
```

I found it could be a problem with the os path, so I tried the following but it didn't fix the issue.

```
import os, sys
from PIL import Image
jpg = Image.open(os.path.join(sys.path[0], 'static/images/image.jpg'))
```

How can I open a static file whether running locally or on Bluemix?

```
myproject/
    static/
        images/
            image.jpg
    myapp.py
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using a relative path, which is relative to the current working directory. In development, you're running from the app's directory. In production, the WSGI server is running the app, and was not launched in that directory. Build an absolute path instead. [`app.static_folder`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Flask.static_folder) is the path to the base static folder.

```
os.path.join(app.static_folder, 'images', 'image.jpg')
```